# Notifying Picasso of Server Side Image Change

Tags: java, android, http, picasso

I am using `Picasso` library in my Android app to load images from a `HTTP` server written in `Java`. I was wondering when `Picasso` caches images, how does it notice image change on the server.

After searching I found the solution: Adding a "Last-Modified" header. The way for generating it is to get the file's Last Modification Date:

```
 file.getAbsoluteFile().lastModified();
```

But I don't know how I should put that in a header.

I really appreciate if you can help me to achieve this.

My current header:

```
  Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
                      h.add("Content-Type", "Image");
                      h.add("Cache-Control","must-revalidate");
```

Comment: Please see the grammatical changes I made in your question. Try to learn and use them in the future.

Comment: im persian, not arab :)

Comment: OK. Let's give your question an up-vote to attract more people to it.

Comment: Version 2.5.0 (not released at the time of this comment but will be very soon). provides the ability to tell Picasso to ignore the disk cache and go fetch the image from the network. See memoryPolicy and networkPolicy APIs in 2.5.0.